# Loading image from resource in .NET MAUI raises questions

Tags: maui, visual-studio-2022

This code will load an image from the Resources/Images folder in a .NET MAUI application.

```cs
IImage image;
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Solitaire.Resources.Images.deck.png"))
{
#if IOS || ANDROID
        // PlatformImage isn't currently supported on Windows.
        image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
#elif WINDOWS
        image = new W2DImageLoadingService().FromStream(stream);
#endif
}
```

When I have setup "Windows Machine" as debugging target ...

[image]

... Visual studio grays out all of the code that will assign to `image`.

[image]

But setting a breakpoint in the `#elif WINDOWS` section will still result in a hit.
[image]

...but how was I able to run the code in the first place. One using is not even defined.

[image]

Finally, if I remove all preprocessor directives to only run this on windows, `W2DImageLoadingService` is not defined ...

[image]

... but that was not a problem when the code was wrapped in `#elif WINDOWS`.

- Why is everything grayed out?
- Why did I hit the breakpoint anyway?
- What is Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D?
- How could I run when the using was not recognized?
- What is W2DImageLoadingService? Where do I get it?
- Did I use the W2DImageLoadingService class when my app actually was running (when `#elif WINDOWS` was still there) and if so, how could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

I have tested the image you provided and it worked well.

Here is the full code:

```
#if IOS || ANDROID || MACCATALYST
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Platform;
#elif WINDOWS
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
#endif
using System.Reflection;
using IImage = Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.IImage;
namespace MauiApp2;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
      int count = 0;

      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        IImage image;
        Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MauiApp2.Resources.Images.test.png"))
        {
#if IOS || ANDROID || MACCATALYST
    // PlatformImage isn't currently supported on Windows.
    image = PlatformImage.FromStream(stream);
#elif WINDOWS
            image = new W2DImageLoadingService().FromStream(stream);
#endif
        }

        if (image != null)
        {
          //  canvas.DrawImage(image, 10, 10, image.Width, image.Height);
        }
    }
}
```

And the result image:

[image]

**Note:** Please make sure the part of blue rectangle of the image is **.net7.0-windows 10.0.19041.0** in your project.

**Update:** When I use Ctrl + Left tap getting into the source of in my visual studio and I see:

```
namespace Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D
{
    public class W2DImageLoadingService : IImageLoadingService
    {
        public IImage FromStream(Stream stream, ImageFormat formatHint = ImageFormat.Png)
        {
            return W2DImage.FromStream(stream, formatHint);
        }
    }
}
```

So the `W2DImageLoadingService` is a class of the `Microsoft.Maui.Graphics.Win2D` which is the special api for windows. In addition, you can check [the source code on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Graphics/src/Graphics/Platforms/Windows/PlatformImage.cs). The `PlatformImage` will also be suppurted on the windows in the later version.

I use the Visual Studio 2022 17.6.5 for now.

Comment: Yes, I am able to load the image but still I have all those questions.

Comment: In my pictrue, you can see the `#if Windows` is not grayed out. In addition, you hit the breakpoint because you run the project on the windows platform. @AndersLindén

Comment: Can you see where W2DImageLoadingService  is defined?

Comment: Which visual studio version do you run?

Comment: Please check the update part in my answer. @AndersLindén

Comment: @Anders. Most of your confusion should go away if you do what is said: *"Note: Please make sure the part of blue rectangle of the image is .net7.0-windows 10.0.19041.0 in your project."* It’s likely that intellisense wasn’t showing you the Windows build. NOTE: Don’t take away `#if Windows`, unless you also remove all other target platforms from .csproj.